# How to send selected table rows value to another page in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have 2 pages and 2 tables, in page 1(table 1) I want to send selected rows to  page 2(table 2) where in table 2 I show the selected rows

This is the first table in page 1:

```
<table class="src-table">
    <tr>
        <th>Select</th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>Jill</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>Eve</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">
```

Like image below [image]

This is the second table in page 2:

```
<table class="target-table">
    <tr>
        <th>Select</th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Like image below[image]

Comment: Will both tables be visible at the same time or will the "submit" button move the user to the second table?

Comment: @cars10m the button will copy the row to the second table

Comment: Yes, I understood the copying part, but my question was directed at the way these tables are *presented* online: Will they exist "at the same time" (i. e. in two tabs or windows of the browser) or "one after the other" (i. e. the submit button navigates to the next page with table 2)?

Comment: @cars10m the submit button will navigate to the next page with table 2 and show selected row

Comment: In that case my post is probably relevant to your question. Also, please look at the first paragraph there.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need this. You can use `localStorage`.

`localStorage` not working in the sandbox. But you can use it your application as well.

run `storeItems` when you need to save selected to store (for example on element select)
run `appendStoredToAnouther` on window event `window.onload` on page with the target table

```js
function storeItems() {
  const selectedItems = document.querySelectorAll("#first-table .selected");
  const selectedHtml = nodeListToString(selectedItems);
  
  localStorage.add('selectedTableItems', selectedHtml);
}

function nodeListToString(nodeList) {
  let string = '';
  nodeList.forEach(function(node) {
    string += node.outerHTML;
  });
  return string;
}

function appendStoredToAnouther() {
  const itemsHtml = window.localStorage.get('selectedTableItems');
  
  const targetTable = document.getElementById('target-table');
  targetTable.innerHTML = itemsHtml + targetTable.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<table id="first-table">
  <tr class="selected">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Selected</td>
    <td>Item</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selected">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Selected</td>
    <td>Item</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Not Selected</td>
    <td>Item</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" onclick="storeItems()">Send to anouther</button>
<button type="button" onclick="appendStoredToAnouther()">Append stored to anouther</button>

<table id="target-table">
  <tr class="selected">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Selected</td>
    <td>Item</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Not Selected</td>
    <td>Item</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below I demonstrated how some lines could be carried over from one table to another one on a following page. However, since both pages are probably hosted on the same server it is in most cases more practical to first collect some unique identifiers for the selected table records, transmit them to the next page and then get the actual table contents from the original data source again (in many cases a database table or view). This approach will also make your page safer against unauthorised injections.

In case that the tables are to be shown in two *consecutive* pages you can do the following:

```js
// shortcut for utility function querySelectorAll():
const qsa=(s,o)=>[...(o||document)['querySelectorAll'](s)];
const log=qsa('#log')[0];

qsa('#submit')[0].addEventListener('click',function(){
 var dat="tbl="+JSON.stringify(
   qsa('tr',qsa('.src-table')[0]).filter(tr=>qsa('input:checked',tr).length)
                            .map(tr=>qsa('td',tr).slice(1)
                            .map(td=>td.innerHTML))
 );
 log.innerHTML+="<hr>dat:"+dat;
 log.innerHTML+="\nwindow.location=\"page2.html?\"+encodeURIComponent(dat)";

 // this second part would be placed in the onload section if the next page:
 log.innerHTML+='var dat=window.location.search.substr(1)'
  
 var args=dat.split("&").reduce((a,v)=>{
   var t=v.split('=');
   a[t[0]]=JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(t[1]));
   return a;},
   {}
 );
  qsa('.trg-table')[0].innerHTML+=
  args.tbl.map((r,i)=>'<tr><td>'+(i+1)+'</td><td>'+r.join('</td><td>')+'</td></tr>').join('');
})
```

```html
<h2>page one</h2>
<table class="src-table">
  <tr><th>Select</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Familyname</th></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Jill</td><td>Jones</td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Eve</td><td>Adams</td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">

<h2>this would be the second page</h2>
<table class="trg-table">
  <tr><th>no</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Familyname</th></tr>
</table>
<pre id="log"></pre>
```

As this is a sandbox the last lines had to modified a bit. In your page you should *actually* redirect your page with the `window.location` assignment.

On the second page you then need to read the passed information from `window.location.search` and use that information to append it to your table there.

Comment: hi @cars10m iam using laravel, how can i use `thislog.innerHTML+="\nwindow.location=\"page2.html?\"+encodeURIComponent(dat)";` i want to route the page to /po (the second page)